# Formly fields not updating the hideExpression attribute on a field when model changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm sorry to have posted this in here since I tried to go here: help.angular-formly.com but there was no content there or removed.

I have a hide expression as so:

```
{
    key: "rotation_speed",
    type: "select",
    noFormControl: true,
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Animation Speed',
      required: true,
      placeholder: 'Animation Speed',
      valueProp: "value",
      labelProp: "name",
      options: [
        {
          'name' : 'Fast Clockwise',
          'value' : '-10'
        },
        {
          'name' : 'Medium Clockwise',
          'value' : '-5'
        }
      ]
    },
    hideExpression: 'model.img_type === "regular"',
}
```

and the formly fields in frontend as this:

```
<formly-form model="panoFactory.presentation.scenes[$index]" fields="scene_fields"></formly-form>
```

I verified that the model changes in the frontend but the hideExpression isn't getting updated probably due to some scoping issues. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you please share img_type fields configuration                                        and remove the Comma(,) after the hideExpression attribute

Comment: I removed the comma @KannanThangadurai. it's still doesn't work as expected. so after I do certain action on the UI like click inside that field then and only then it is hiding this select dropdown, since at that time the model looks like is getting updated. Weirdly there are other fields in the same form which use the same model and are update perfectly when I change from model to model. Definitely some scoping issues but unable to figure it out.

Comment: 'model && model.img_type === "regular"' can you change the expression like that, I doubting, some were evaluating expression got undefined error

Comment: I tried this method. Didn't seem to work. Maybe I termed it incorrectly. The fields are changing according to the hideExpression only if I go into it and select an option, then it's realizing that the select shouldn't be there in the first place and goes away. This is frustrating.